# what is this icon and how to get rid of it

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I'm in Visual Studio 2008 editor and I somehow managed to place an icon in the debug column that I have no earthly idea what it is or how to remove it?

[image]

Comment: Are you using any extension like Resharper or JustCode ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a task list shortcut that are added by going (Edit -> Bookmarks -> Add Task List Shortcut). Remove it by going to line the arrow is on and going (Edit -> Bookmarks -> Remove Task List Shortcut). That should be all that needs to be done.

Comment: +1 After using VS for so long I just came to know, it has task list, thanks

Comment: You can also use Ctrl+K, Ctrl+H to toggle it (maybe you pressed that).  If you want to see shortcuts, open the Task List, and select "Shortcuts" from the drop-down at the top left.

Answer (score 3):

This icon is task linked to this place. Ctrl W + T will show all tasks. Remove that task shortcut.